How can I get the path of an unhandled exception in C# .NET project?
I have a method like the following
var ex = Server.GetLastError();
Server.ClearError();
Response.Redirect($"~/MyErrorPage.html");

that reports an error. But it does not log away the path, for example if I am running locally, I want it to log away c:\development\....
I have the request which can get the physical path, but how can I add this as an extra string to a property in the exception, like the ex.Message ?
How can I log this ?
I tried to do a string concat but that didn't work

What is your logging setup currently?

I am using bugsnag . I have the web.config configured setup to capture unhandled exceptions . But it does not log away the path. I was wondering if i can log some metadata on every error ?

What's the point though? You already know where you redirect to, don't you?

no the unhandled error in bugsnag doesnt capture the path. It could come from any where ?

Oh, that path ... ok. Now it makes sense.


how can I add this as an extra string to a property in the exception, like the ex.Message ?


I tried to do a string concat but that didn't work

You could instantiate a new Exception with the info you need:
string physicalPath = Request.PhysicalPath;
var ex = Server.GetLastError();
var enhancedMessage = $"{ex.Message} | Physical Path: {physicalPath}";
var newEx = new Exception(enhancedMessage, ex);

Or you could make your own Exception:
public class KatesException : Exception {
public string PhysicalPath {get; set;}
}


That did not do anything to the error message , still the same. It is a bugsnag error /exception ?

Right, I just read the comments then, you should have mentioned that in your question or [edit]ed it after it was brought up. My answer is still valid you can pass any object that inherits from System.Exception to the Notify method bugsnag.Notify(ex); - Also what are you using, this looks like ASP.Net WebForms?
